# Minimum rotation to get the maximum value

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

I recently solved a coding challenge in one of the challenge papers that my IT teacher gave to us. It was a seemingly simple, but fun challenge, so I thought it will make fun golfing.

### The task

Given an input of a 2x2 matrix that contains 4 strictly positive integers (i.e. non-negative and non-zero), like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

We call the value of the matrix given is \$\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{c}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\dfrac{b}{d}\right\rfloor\$.

Your task is to calculate the amount of rotation needed to get the maximum value of the matrix.

A rotation rotates the matrix 90 degrees clockwise.

### Input and Output

The input can be a 2x2 matrix (as shown above), a flattened list `[a b c d]`, or any other reasonable input.

Note that with the case of flattened lists, the numbers can be in any order you preferred. (e.g. `[a b d c]`).

The output must show a number that is the amount of rotation required.

### Clarifications

- In case of a tie, we will choose the one with the least amount of rotation needed.
- In case where no rotation is required, we simply output `0` or `4` (the maximal rotation).
- The division used here is integer division (i.e. the result of the division will always be an integer).

### Examples

```
[a b c d] -> output
[1 2 3 4] -> 3
[5 7 9 2] -> 1
[5 6 7 8] -> 0 or 4
[1 9 2 3] -> 3
[2 5 6 8] -> 3
```

These examples are hand-calculated and written, so correct me if I'm wrong!

As always, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25259/107017)

Comment: Can you provide some more test cases?

Comment: Can we output 4 instead of 0 (i.e. if the input is the maximal rotation)?

Comment: How should we handle `0` in the denominator?

Comment: Will the values be positive integers? For ties, can we output any of the tied rotations?

Comment: @dingledooper The integers input will need to be strictly positive. I will clarify it.

Comment: @xnor In case of ties, we chose the one that has the least amount of rotation needed. I will also clarify this one

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer I have clarified that the numbers in the matrix will not be zero.

Comment: Shouldn't `[5 6 7 8]` be `3`?

Comment: Is it integer division?

Comment: @AZTECCO Ah, that would explain why `[5 6 7 8]` is `0` instead of `3`. 

Comment: @AZTECCO Good catch! I have clarified this in the Clarifications section

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ZU$Ƭ:/€INM’Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8qVOXYGiv9R01rPP18HzXMfLhj0f/D7UBu5P//0dGGOkaxOtHGOiaxsToK0dGmOuZAriVQEMw11zEFcs2AZCwA)

### How it works

```
ZU$Ƭ:/€INM’Ḣ - Main link. Takes a matrix M on the left
  $Ƭ         - Do the following until a repeat is found:
Z            -   Transpose
 U           -   Reverse rows. This rotates clockwise 90°
      €      - To each rotation:
    :/       -   Reduce each column by integer division
       I     - Get the (negative) differences
        N    - Negate
         M   - Get the index of the maximal element
          ’  - Decrement
           Ḣ - Get the first (minimal) element
```

Comment: Not _quite_ right. You need to use integer division (`:`) e.g. `[[7,5],[6,5]]` should give `2`, but with plain division you will find `0` instead. Also, "In case of a tie, we will choose the one with the least amount of rotation needed.", so you need to add `Ḣ` after `M` e.g. `[[5,7],[5,6]]` should give `0` (or `4` since that's allowed) but we'll get `[0,1,3]` once we're using `:`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yep, recently noticed the changes to the challenge. I'll update once I'm back at my laptop, thanks for the suggested changes :)

Answer (score 4):

## Excel (ms365), <s>153</s>, 148 bytes

-5 bytes by [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)

```
=LET(a,INT(A1/C1)-INT(B1/D1),b,INT(C1/D1)-INT(A1/B1),c,INT(D1/B1)-INT(C1/A1),d,INT(B1/A1)-INT(D1/C1),m,MAX(a,b,c,d),IF(m=a,0,IF(m=b,1,IF(m=c,2,3))))
```

---

Original 153 bytes answer:

```
=XMATCH(9,BYROW(REDUCE(A1:D1,ROW(1:3),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,SORTBY(TAKE(a,-1),{2,4,1,3})))),LAMBDA(c,SUM(INT(INDEX(c,{1,2})/INDEX(c,{3,4}))*{1,-1}))),-1)-1
```

It's painstaking in Excel, but my thought process here was:

- `REDUCE(A1:D1,ROW(1:3),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,SORTBY(TAKE(a,-1),{2,4,1,3}))))` - Create a vertical array where we keep stacking a 90° tilted array to our previous array;
- `BYROW(~,LAMBDA(c,SUM(INT(INDEX(c,{1,2})/INDEX(c,{3,4}))*{1,-1})))` - Loop over each row from said array and do the math as per question: Devide the 1st and 3rd integer by the 2nd and 4th, discard the fractional part and do a negative summation of the resulting integers;
- `XMATCH(9,~,-1)-1` - Find a nine (the largest possible outcome) or the next lower value. Deduct one from the given index.

[image]

Comment: @jdt, if it works it works! I'll edit in the option but will leave the original too.

Comment: @jdt yes with stuff like `TOCOL()` you can. Where is your mind going? I'm intriqued =)

Comment: Using a HLOOKUP or something  instead of the nested IF statements but i think it will be longer.

Comment: There might be some potential in doing something like this: `=LET(s,{0,2,1,3;2,3,0,1;3,1,2,0;1,0,3,2},a,MAKEARRAY(2,4,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x=1,INT(OFFSET(A1,0,INDEX(s,y,1))/OFFSET(A1,0,INDEX(s,y,2)))-INT(OFFSET(A1,0,INDEX(s,y,3))/OFFSET(A1,0,INDEX(s,y,4))),-y))),-VLOOKUP(MAX(a),a, 1))`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

Expects four BigInts as `[a,b,c,d]`.

```javascript
A=>A.map(m=(_,i)=>(([a,b,c,d]=A,v=a/c-b/d)<=m||(j=i,m=v),A=[c,a,d,b]))|j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1dC4IwGEbv@xW73ODVZVYm9Ar7HSIxp4binGR45X9fM8qgr4tz9Rye08hRDupS91evM0VpK7QCE@Fr2VON9AQ1w4TSVEIOCooMBYwoufJyXrAj6mmiDdagcWQgMFUgoYA8Y2xqrDLdYNrSb82ZVjQNOiAvnEI4J@vVF2vjCB3bpxW@Wzu3Ro74bj@s4NMisHdEjsPfYrxUfxXnda7uHctXaG8)

#### Commented

```javascript
A =>                    // A[] = input list
A.map(                  // repeat 4 times,
  m =                   //   with m initialized to a non-numeric value
  (_, i) => (           //   and i as the rotation index:
    (                   //
      [a, b, c, d] = A, //     split A into [a, b, c, d]
      v = a / c - b / d //     compute the value v for this rotation
    ) <= m              //     do nothing if it's less than or equal to m
    || (j = i, m = v),  //     otherwise update m and the best index j
    A = [c, a, d, b]    //     rotate the flattened view of the matrix
  )                     //     (see below)
) | j                   // end of map(); return j
```

#### Rotation

Below are the details of the 90° clockwise rotation of the flattened matrix:

$$[a,b,c,d]\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}a&\color{blue}b\\\color{green}c&\color{green}d\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}\color{green}c&\color{blue}a\\\color{green}d&\color{blue}b\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow[c,a,d,b]$$

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4FDøí})ε`÷Æ}Zk
```

Input as a matrix. Outputs `0` if no rotation is necessary.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxM3l8I7Da2s1z21NOLz9cFttVPb//9HRhjpGsTrRxjomsbEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/EzeXwzsOr63VPLc14fD2w221Udn/df5HR0cb6hjF6kQb65jExuooREeb6pgDuZZAQSjXDMg117GAcA11LIFcIx1jCNdIxxTINYPJmoK5IDI2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
4F       # Loop 4 times:
  D      #  Duplicate the current matrix
         #  (which will be the implicit input-matrix in the first iteration)
   øí    #  Rotate it once clockwise:
   ø     #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    í    #   Reverse each inner row
 })      # After the loop: wrap the stack of five matrices into a list
   ε     # Map over each matrix:
    `    #  Pop and push both pairs/rows separated to the stack
     ÷   #  Integer-divide the items at the same positions in the pairs
      Æ  #  Reduce the pair by subtracting
   }Z    # After the map: push the maximum (without popping the list)
     k   # Get the (first 0-based) index of this maximum in the list
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 81 bytes

Thanks to @chunes for -22

```
[ 3 [ dup reverse flip ] times 4array [ first2 v/ vfloor first2 - ] map arg-max ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BTsMwEEX3OcW_QIIaSlvgAIgNEkKsqi6sMAaLxDHjSdQqyknYZFOu0jP0NnUcAht_682bkf73j1aF1DycT68vj08Pd_gktlTC01dDtiCPSslHfDLd2EJMbT0Uszp4OCaRg2NjZTJaGo_5_-2M9sLK4z5JuqRDhwVy9CGvsQzZR3aDdWS3cTazVWRrbP7YIhgjy8P2zPJgjmz16_XHRnS6OT9vg7TFW-PA1BJ7gi6Nww5iqtBqGSsEQxv2kqO9QqvLuuYZpEGtlAtV39NK7bGbDh9Hlk3_YZjyAg)

### Explanation

| code | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `3 [ dup reverse flip ] times 4array` | Generate a 4-item array of all rotations, by sequential `reverse` and `flip`s |
| `[ first2 v/ vfloor first2 - ] map` | Calculate the value of each matrix, according to the scheme. (First does vectorized floor division, then outputs difference of first 2 items.) |
| `arg-max` | Index of the largest item |

Comment: `[ floor ] map` -> `vfloor` and `[ supremum ] keep index` -> `arg-max`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, btw, and nice answer. It's great to see a Factor answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>116</s> 99 bytes

```java
a->{int r=0,i=-1,m=0,t;for(;++i<4;a=new int[]{a[2],a[0],a[3],a[1]})if((t=a[0]/a[2]-a[1]/a[3])>m){m=t;r=i;}return r;}
```

-17 bytes thanks to *@Neil* by taking four loose integer inputs instead of an integer-array

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZDNasMwEITveQrhk4zXTvPTNq2qvEFzybH0oB@7KLXlIK8DJfjZXUkxJaEEwYc0jJjZPYiTyA/6e1S16DryLow9zwgxFktXCVWSXXhGgSgaKCBQRqpInTLvGWYeHQo0iuyIJXykAiQo0Gm@PQef4w9geL6Axl@QVa2jLMvM25ohFyC4AsU1aC5BckxNRanX5yqXc51um/TccGSOGza4EntniWPDyELqsZe1T53CT63RpPGD0D06Y78@PkV6GQLLDukClrCCdew8SY/wDC@wvJWevLi5lhbBA6traQnBt7n9GM@/lcRW0XFviZeO@58Oy6ZoeyyOvj3WloosgSSTkSpSZ8krSTJbqL8dT4HD@As)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,c,d)->{ // Method with four integer parameters and integer return-type
 int r=0,    //  Result-index, starting at 0
     i=-1,   //  Index-integer, starting at -1
     m=0,    //  Max value, starting at 0
     t;      //  Temp-integer, uninitialized
     ++i<4   //  Loop `i` in the range (-1,4) (or [0,3]):
     ;       //    After every iteration:
      t=a,a=c,c=d,d=b,b=t)
             //     Rotate: change a,b,c,d to c,a,d,b
   if((t=a/c-b/d)
             //    Set `t` to a//c-b//d
      >m){   //    And if `t` is larger than `m`:
     m=t;    //     Set maximum `m` to this `t`
     r=i;}   //     And update the result with the current index `i`
  return r;} //  Finally, return the result-index `r`
```

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVDLasMwELznK4RPMl47jZO2aVXlD5pLjqUHPeyi1JaDvAkU4293ZSmUhCIYaYcRMztHcRH5UX9PqhF9T96FscOCEGOxcrVQFdnPYyCIojMKCIOMl4qXTpmXjQsPPQo0iuyJJXyiAiQo0Gm@G2ad4w9geL6C1j@Q1Z2jLMvM24YhFyC4AsU1aC5BckxNTannlyqXS53u2nRoOTLHDRtdhWdniWPjxGbX01k23vVqfumMJq3fhR7QGfv18SnSuAdWPdIVlLCGTch8pR7hGV6gvKeePLm9pVazBta3VAmzbnv/MZx/lYRUQRF7jDXGFmOJMePhp8eqLbozFiefHhtLRZZAksmAKqDOkleSZLZQfx1fDcfpFw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil Ah, of course! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c,d{(1..4).max_by{a,b,c,d=c,a,d,b
[a/c-b/d,-_1%-4]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3rXTtEnWSdJJ1Uqo1DPX0TDT1chMr4pMqq6Gitsk6iTopOklc0Yn6ybpJ-ik6uvGGqromsbW1UBPKCxTcog11FIx0FIx1FExiFZQVdO0UjLlAwqY6CuY6CpZASaiwIUzYDCxjARU2UMgvUjDhgppkCTEMxSSgAEQXTIsxxPoFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 62 bytes

```factor
[ 4 [ -rotd swap 4dup [ swap /i ] 2bi@ - ] replicate arg-max ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZC_TsNADMb3PMWHmK_QNEAKUsWGWFgQU9ThuDpwapocPkcUVX0SlizwFjxI3wYrrVIkvPjPz_4s-_O7tE4a7nY_T4_3D3fXWBLXVGFl5RWR3lqqHcURrYVtRGAS-QjsazlC3CTJJoHaBmOkmCDDVrMTmBkmB3CBK0wVDmA8gEtF-RGcD1LTXuyfVNrP5H_B9quV0uS7WaG7CxhuZIH4bgOyRRu00sdnHnOkz_4WRgOmUHlnhWD5xazsGvODymmB0nOUTLv04tBE0n8ERLFuOYKryPK-tev2_hc)

Takes 4 integers as input in the order `a b c d`.

- `4 [ ... ] replicate` Create a sequence of 4 elements where the elements are determined by the output of `[ ... ]`.

Now let's take a look at what happens inside the `replicate` quotation:

```
                  ! 2 5 6 8          (example input)
-rotd             ! 6 2 5 8
swap              ! 6 2 8 5          (this is the next rotation of the matrix)
4dup              ! 6 2 8 5 6 2 8 5
[ swap /i ] 2bi@  ! 6 2 8 5 0 0      (apply [ swap /i ] to the top two pairs of items)
-                 ! 6 2 8 5 0        (so 0 is the first element of the sequence)
                  ! 6 2 8 5          (now the next element will be determined...)
```

- `arg-max` Get the index of the largest element.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c,d,*m:m.index(max(m))if 3<len(m)else f(c,a,d,b,*m,a//c-b//d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBDsIgFIThtZ6CJa8ZJS1aa6MnMS6gQCQptKld6Onx1cUkXyb//F1fU9alhPtoknVGGFgMcKhSn44xO/@RyfCIYhD6NvrM9uPbiyAHGC4ttzBKDQerlKMSpkVEEbN4yBoNNE4EecYFVzR/teyOVW8PNKvB9nb07Pe7eYl5lUFWkaj8AA)

Answer (score 2):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, 34 bytes

```
03 24 e7 07 0f b4 08 bc 07 bc b0 fb f3 f5 b1 fb
f2 f6 ad 1b bd 42 a4 bf 2f 46 a4 46 01 3c f1 da
70 47
```

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    // doesn't work with clang?!
    // .arch armv7ve
    .arch armv7-a
    .arch_extension idiv
    .globl rotation
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    // input: r0=A, r1=B, r2=D, r3=C
    // output: r12
    // Uses r0-r7, r12
rotation:
    // Register aliases since it is otherwise confusing
    A       .req r0
    B       .req r1
    D       .req r2
    C       .req r3
    rot     .req r4
    res     .req r12
    max     .req r7
    // Current rotation. This loops backwards, so we rotate backwards.
    movs    rot, #3
    // 3 << 31 = 0x80000000 = INT_MIN
    lsls    max, rot, #31
.Lloop:
    // Rotate COUNTER-CLOCKWISE by pushing/popping in a different order
    // Push and pop are the only things that make Thumb viable for this :)
    // A, B, D, C = B, D, C, A
    push    {A, B, D, C}
    pop     {C}
    pop     {A, B, D}
    // r5 = A / C
    udiv    r5, A, C
    // r6 = B / D
    udiv    r6, B, D
    // r5 = (A / C) - (B / D)
    subs    r5, r5, r6
    // Is this less than or equal to the max?
    cmp     r5, max
    // If so, save the new lowest rotation and the new max
    itt     ge
    movge   max, r5
    movge   res, rot
    // Loop while rot >= 0
    subs    rot, rot, #1
    bge    .Lloop
    // Return
    bx      lr
```

Uses the idiv extension.

Accepts arguments as `r0=A`, `r1=B`, `r2=D`, `r3=C`, and returns 0, 1, 2, or 3 in `r12`.

This cannot be called from C so I provide a wrapper which allows it to be called with this signature:

```c
int rotation_c_wrapper(int A, int B, int D, int C);
```

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .globl rotation_c_wrapper
    // Wrapper to be called from C
    // int rotation_c_wrapper(int a, int b, int d, int c);
rotation_c_wrapper:
    // Save callee-saved registers
    push    {r4-r7, lr}
    // call the function
    bl      rotation
    // move result to r0
    mov     r0, r12
    // Restore callee-saved registers and return
    pop     {r4-r7, pc}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 92 bytes

```c
y,r;g(a,b,c,d,i){y=i>3?0:g(c,a,d,b,i+1)<(a=a/c-b/d)?r=i,a:y;}f(a,b,c,d){g(a,b,c,d,r=0);r=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LDoIwEEX3fkVjYtKJl5SXCtTKj7gpJZAuRNO4IYRvr0BC3HQ758w9JuqN8X6Ekz3XaGDQwtI0KvvI6rjquYFeTg3sOaE710oLEzWipdopC12Ncu72R5r@G07FJJ1ycvYvbQdO04F9nB2@HT@eWvYcjuh4ghQZciIpRBbgF9xQIt14EuTXxSg2HrO3Y3kwUq6ZTWKhSop1p9iF2f8A)

- function *f* initializes gobal *r* to 0 which is kinda default result.
  Then calls *g* which recursively sets *r* when a greater combination happens.
- *g* sets global *y* to a greater value or itself or 0 if the recursion loop is completed(*i>3*), there cannot be greater value less than 0.

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##pc9RS8MwEAfwdz/FMTAk3b@s3apOs3wTX9K0GYGmjixWYdtXN4YNwQeFifd0HP/7cWdKM@hxm1IR4THBScuLAI0WBp04BMZ4VAFOeVUJOSm9MGW76OS08ccj92pCEZUT0s3nm4Yxy6u8qNGhFfKUvHYjF3S4oVxujBTkubWcBVANWoJWoEZcxruQM5bPQr9/HSIpuu1A/fuuN7Hvnmj1PM5AIYe/IXegB9Bjpq5D6l@Q@7Ozvg6p6CVQ85NUX27Jb/3jp@XXReu/Iqf0Yeygt/tUvn0C)

Comment: @jdt I checked the IO rules again and it seems that your suggestion is fine, you are talking a reference and output to it, the internal use of it may seem a bit cheaty but it's clever, I think you can post it and also post a tip for golfing in C

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 99 bytes

```perl
sub f{($a,$b,$c,$d,$i,$m,$I)=@_;$v=$a/$c-$b/$d;$i-4?f($c,$a,$d,$b,$i+1,$v>$m?($v,$i):($m,$I)):$I|0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LToNQFEXnfMVOcwyXeEiLfSmEwrQxsRNnlTQ8DVEotpRoar@dXu51YDo8e@29TpMfPud9fzwlKM6CYqaEKWXKmEqmimlt@eHOo86neEypTcmYMo9KexYUYijGqitH5b3D1K2oCgR18rRcofeWS@vfyaUv9gdhAFtsHcYDY8qYRfBXmCJiDeaMJeNJYgWc/2Ch2OPNwtF1absBMtKj28UQKbZUYIIIlnGWDKh@BJV1w6D8u7HgI6Sd90dA7/tWRoUIh46l8@ZQ1m2B0Z29OA63JKfWhaoMt/TkaZtnrlIOibS4yvVWj/Qj5F9aHsDcf5hwYb5sXrF5Nj3j0l8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζＮεＦ⁴«⊞υ⁻÷θζ÷ηε≔θδ≔ζθ≔εζ≔ηε≔δη»Ｉ⌕υ⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7LCsIwEAXQdfsVs5xA3PkCV6IIXSj9hdhEM2BTm0eRit8em25aujzDXO6ttLBVI14xFuYd/C3Ud2WxZYd8br1wv7Aa/Ggs4JrBN8/K4DQGDlcywWFh/Jk6kgpbDj3jMB00B8XYEM6OztHTpA85Y8@hnVGl/MQxPVFySDt/eWnJeDwJ5/FCRo5LxIfqUGNgqS7GDWxhB/u46l5/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζＮε
```

Input `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Repeat four times.

```
⊞υ⁻÷θζ÷ηε
```

Push the value of the current rotation to the predefined empty list.

```
≔θδ≔ζθ≔εζ≔ηε≔δη
```

Rotate the matrix.

```
»Ｉ⌕υ⌈υ
```

Find the index of the maximum value.

I tried working with lists but the best I could do was 42 bytes:

```
≔Ｅ⁴ＮθＦ⁴«⊞υθ≔Ｅ1302§θＩκθ»ＵＭυ⁻÷⊟ι⊟ι÷⊟ι⊟ιＩ⌕υ⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7bCoJAEIav9SkGr2bBoIMdoCsxAi8MX2FTyyV31T2IED375qGgm64G/vnm@ycrqcxqWlkbKsXuAhPaYOBDLBqjL4ZfC4mE@NCSo3urJWBA4Ok6qVElmjl2fi691Wa59nwIdSzyosfWh4gqjQ/ylbzcgYtqzqnIR0PChFEYC31iHcsLTOsG2cDOk4yf/FmRwZZKJjROFWf2EdKeccPRTIS1B9jBHrZ20VVv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `d b c a`. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ⁴Ｎθ
```

Input `d`, `b`, `c` and `a` into a list.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Repeat four times.

```
⊞υθ
```

Push the list to the predefined empty list.

```
≔Ｅ1302§θＩκθ
```

"Rotate" the list.

```
»ＵＭυ⁻÷⊟ι⊟ι÷⊟ι⊟ι
```

Replace each list with the value of the matrix it represents.

```
Ｉ⌕υ⌈υ
```

Find the index of the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 84 bytes

```c
*t,m,v,i;f(*r,a,b,c,d){r?t=r,i=m=0:0;v=a/c-b/d;v<m||(m=v,*t=i);i++<4&&f(0,c,a,d,b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pc9Ra8IwEAfw932KQ1hJ67/Yarc5Y9gX2UuaNBJoOolZN1C/@rKgDPag4Ng9Hcf/ftypUvVy2MRYBDiMsNywwkOihYLO9/4lCA8rnKhWFR@FnKmynWk@rt3hwJwYUQRhc26n03WTZYZVaU9Co835MTppB5bT/o5S2SGQ56fWsMyDatActAA1@Xm89Slj2MR3u/c@kKB7Deo@t50KnV7R4nWYgHwK/0IeQE@g50TdhtRXkMeTs7wNqejNU3NJqs@3pLf@8dP856LlX5Fj/FKml5tdLD@@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
 4(:⁽ḭÞC÷-$∩R)_WÞMh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiIDQoOuKBveG4rcOeQ8O3LSTiiKlSKV9Xw55NaCIsIiIsIltbMSwgMl0sIFszLCA0XV1cbltbNSwgN10sIFs5LCAyXV1cbltbNSwgNl0sIFs3LCA4XV1cbltbMSwgOV0sIFsyLCAzXV1cbltbMiwgNV0sIFs2LCA4XV0iXQ==)

Unfortunately useful operator `İ` "collect while unique" currently works bad, so simple for-loop is used.

```
4(     # Open for-loop with 4 iterations
:      # Duplicate
⁽ḭÞC   # Reduce columns by integer division
÷-     # Calculate value
$      # Swap
∩R     # Transpose + Reverse = Rotate
)      # Close loop 
_      # Pop unnecessary
W      # Wrap stack into list
ÞM     # Find all indices of maximum
h      # Pick and print one (first)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
4o ñ@zX yÈrzÃr-
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=NG8g8UB6WCB5yHJ6w3It&input=WwpbMSAyXQpbMyA0XQpd)

```
4o ñ@zX yÈrzÃr-     :Implicit input of 2D-array
4o                  :Range [0,4)
   ñ                :Sort by
    @               :Passing each X through the following function
     zX             :Rotate U clockwise X times
        y           :Transpose
         È          :Map
          r         :  Reduce by
           z        :  Integer division
            Ã       :End map
             r-     :Reduce by subtraction
                    :Implicit output of last element
```