# Remove the last 'n' occurences of a substring from a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string and a substring and a positive integer `n`.

Remove the `n` occurences of a substring from the *end* of the **originally given string**. If the substring is not present in the string or the number of times the substring appears is less than `n`, then the output is the original string. No space should be present in place of the removed substring.

#### RULES

1. The shortest code wins the challenge (as this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)).

#### Test-cases:

```
Input:
String = "Cats do meow-meow while lions do not meow."
Substring = "meow"
n = 2

Output:
"Cats do meow- while lions do not ."


Input:
String = "Cats do not memeowow, they do meow-ing."
Substring = "meow"
n = 2

Output:
"Cats do not meow, they do -ing."


Input:
String = "Cats do meow-meow while lions do not meow."
Substring = "meow"
n = 4

Output:
"Cats do meow-meow while lions do not meow."
```

Comment: This would benefit from more test cases

Comment: What happens if removing a substring once would create more of it, like `memeowow`? What if matches overlap?

Comment: The question is expanded. Please check . Thanks

Comment: I find the question pretty clear now, but it would still benefit from some test cases where the substring isn't present and where it's present <n times.

Comment: The phrase 'Remove the 'n' duplicates of substring from the end of' is also a bit confusing.  When I first read it, I assumed that the substrings would be at the end of the string, not also contained within it.  It only becomes clear from the examples...

Comment: @anoman I think _xnor_'s question regarding the new test case was mostly what the expected output would be with `n=3`. Would it result in `"Cats do not , they do -ing."` (3 removed) or `"Cats do not memeowow, they do meow-ing."` (none removed, since there are only 2)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen As made clear now in question, it would return the original string without doing anything. I am very sorry for not framing question properly.

Comment: Do we have to account for case-sensitivity?

Comment: @JvdV I'd assume `A!=a`, but op would have to clarify

Comment: @Baby_Boy Yes. I googled and got that unlike python some languages are not case-sensitive. Actually I am a newbie in computer world and learning basic python in my school. .That is also a reason that I cannot chose to accept any answer. Even the python codes below are beyond my understanding as I am learning basic python. I can't even got to know at first slight that the python codes below were in python or some alien code language. Anyway , thanks all.

Comment: @anoman very nice question for being that new to CS in general

Comment: Follow up question on the nested substrings. What is your desired result for `Cats do meow not memeowow, they do meow-ing.` where n=3?

Comment: @JvdV It has been already told that it has to be removed from **original** string. Hence , the output will be : "Cats do not meow, they do -ing." which is similar to the second example.

Comment: @Baby_Boy Thanks very much :)

Comment: @anoman, that's definatelity not the same as the 2nd example. You mentioned that you want to remove the substring n times from the end of the string. People can read this as though you are looping n times. Note that as is, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253746/100057) answer is wrong, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253751/100057) answer is wrong, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253733/100057), [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253758/100057) etc etc etc.

Comment: @JvdV No it cannot mean looping 'n' time because a single thing cannot be removed more than once. Thus, the substring shall be present more than once. If the wording of question is not clear still, please tell what should I edit and with what; so that it can be made clear. Thanks

Comment: I think the term "duplicates" is also a little confusing; it also led me to expect that the substring was expected to be directly repeated n times, with nothing else between, at the end of the string. I would phrase this as "Remove `n` occurrences of the substring from the input. If the input contains *more* than than `n` occurrences of the substring, only the last `n` should be removed. If the input contains fewer than `n` occurrences, it should be returned unchanged".

Comment: What is the expected output for string=`aaa`, substring=`aa`, n=2?

Comment: @Ben Yes , it is better. I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: @att Expected output is "aaa" as stated in the question : *'' If the substring is not present in the string or the number of times the substring appears is less than n, then the output is the original string"*

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes, I was also searching for a better word. As Ben suggested, I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: The substring `aa` appears 2 times in `aaa`, but the occurrences are overlapping.

Comment: @att It will appear two times if and only if, it is read from both left and right side at the same time.

Answer (score 11):

## Excel (ms365), <s>115</s>, 83 bytes

-32 also thanks to [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt) and the idea to split instead of loop.

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,B1),b,ROWS(a),IF(b>C1,CONCAT(IF(SEQUENCE(b)<b-C1,a&B1,a)),A1))
```

[image]

---

**Note**: This answer has been edited to no longer loop to remove the substring from the *end* of the string, but split the input instead. This would now give the appropriate answer for input like 'Cats do meow not memeowow, they do meow-ing.' where 'n=3'.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <del>66</del> <del>53</del> 52 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to @92.100.97.109 (though not exactly in the way they intended)

```python
lambda i,j,k:[i,''.join(a:=i.rsplit(j,k))][len(a)>k]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXISc5NSEhUydbJ0sq2iM3XU1fWy8jPzNBKtbDP1iooLcjJLNIBSmpqx0TmpQGFNu-xYqN5pBUWZeSUaaRpKSflFCiUIrKSjoAShjDQ1FZQVfPOLUhVKMhLzFPy4sOlBV-9akZhcklOpkFpYmpgDVIBFG7oWn9TiYqgVENctWAChAQ)

Returning identity when the occurrences are less than N is annoying.

Comment: <s>[Alternative 53 byte solution](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXMSc5NSEhUydbJ0sq2i1dX1svIz8zQSrWwz9YqKC3IySzSAEpqaOpmx0TmpQAlNW9vsWKhm54KizLwSjTQNpaT8IoUSBFbSUVCCUEaamlzoqlBkIUYtWAChAQ)</s>

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Your version fails if the amount of occurrences exactly equals k but that's' fixable.

Comment: The funny thing is, that (the code that you edited to) is the code that I had originally written, but for some reason I thought it wasn't working properly? I don't know why

Comment: Your version flipped the condition I think, it didn't work properly in the equals case but I'm not really sure what I changed now.

Comment: I wish you hadn't deleted your comment so I could find it again

Comment: Sorry, it's a bad habit

Comment: [51 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3jXMSc5NSEhUydbJ0sq00NHJS8zQSrWwz9YqKC3IySzSAopqaNrbZmlpZmnpZ-ZlAWU2o1mkFRZl5JRppGkpJ-UUKJQispKOgBKGMNDUVlBV884tSFUoyEvMU_Liw6UFX71qRmFySU6mQWliamANUgEUbuhaf1OJiqBUQ1y1YAKEB)  feels like it could go even lower

Comment: @mousetail Hi, I am learning python as my first language but I never saw any code like this.Like the functions I learnt (for,while,if,else) and datatypes(integer,string,list) are not here. This code seems very alien/scary.  Is this a coding  by  hiding functions? Thanks.

Comment: @CursorCoercer ouch my eyes hurt reading that. Nice find

Comment: @anoman Take a look at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python for some info on some of the tricks used

Answer (score 7):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>109</s></sup> <sup><s>107</s></sup> <sup><s>112</s></sup> <sup><s>105</s></sup> 100 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

+5 bytes for fixing an error pointed out by [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100057/jvdv).

```c
f(*a,i,*b,j,n,**r){for(*r=wcsdup(a);i--*n>0;)!bcmp(a+i,b,j)?wcscpy(a+i,a+i+j),n--,i-=j:0;!n?*r=a:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJRT4MwEMff9yk6kimF6yTzxYhzD776DeYeWAezC2sJLWFz4auLV5gOJDGzSXPXP//@uNyVM55GclvXietFIMBbww4keF5OT4nKXS@fl1xvisyNaCgY8@RzENLxmu9R8QWgnS7QwbNjc8bt7yhIxkCw@e4xCMdygZAIs6oW0pB9JKRLR6cRwaVNXnDTpK1gl3WZg1k@BKuwJ@ZxNhS5KqRppYqYWJvlisw7tBN5dfaxKqcOnDNMZqSCnuMlMppsFJEKK4ytS5VAzHt8tKo9MyG3VyHs939w7n9z1ion5rIbbxtnf1ivsPUtbcfaxuGkiWubKbB1QYjhiWjxEavEtR2l5K57XAYrih7fp8PBeXZyCDk/msYuVlMUadj34TCHPhSHPl2k5iJiDQcD9mIaS5tTsKwfxSKAfAOb1wHkpqV02FmO9MR1biepvgVyDpMN1tTkb9K5UJo/dmoc8Hv4alTVnzxJo62uWfkF)

Answer (score 6):

## T-SQL 135 bytes

Is not looping to avoid the string being created again "memeowow"

```sql
WITH c(z)as(SELECT 1UNION ALL 
SELECT charindex(@r,@,z+1)FROM c WHERE z>0)SELECT top(@n)@=stuff(@,z,len(@r),'')FROM
c ORDER BY-z PRINT @
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1660456/remove-a-given-substring-n-number-of-times-from-the-end-of-a-string)**

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>67</s> <s>61</s> 75 bytes

Updated after clarification by OP, which unfortunately made it longer.

```ruby
->s,u,n,*a{s.scan(u){a<<$`.size}
a.size<n||eval("s[a.pop,u.size]='';"*n)
s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3vXXtinVKdfJ0tBKri_WKkxPzNEo1qxNtbFQS9Iozq1JruRLBtE1eTU1qWWKOhlJxdKJeQX6BTilYPNZWXd1aSStPk6u4Fmrk3YLSkmIFt2gl50QgnZKvkJuaX64LIhTKMzJzUhVyMvPzwBJ5-SVgST0lHQUlEANIG8VyoeuHKAPJ55frKJRkpFbCTc3MS8enmQjDwe7CbwOSAcaxEE8uWAChAQ)

Answer (score 6):

#### Python, 51 bytes

```
lambda A,B,n:"".join(A.rsplit(B,n*(n<=A.count(B))))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¡`.gI›I*F«}¹ý
```

Inputs in the order `substring, string, n`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0MIEvXTPRw27PLXcDq2uPbTz8N7//3NT88u5nBNLihVS8hVAHF0QoVCekZmTqpCTmZ8HlsjLLwFL6nEZAQA) or [verify some more `n`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W96bJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2hzYd2vn/0MIEvXS/Rw27/LTcDq2uPbTz8N7/Ov9zU/PLuZwTS4oVUvIVQBxdEKFQnpGZk6qQk5mfB5bIyy8BS@oBAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
¡           # Split the (implicit) second input-sentence on the (implicit) first substring
 `          # Pop and push all parts separated to the stack
  .g        # Get the amount of items on the stack
    I›      # Check if this is larger than the third input-integer `n`
      I*    # Multiply it by the third input-integer `n`
        F   # Loop that many times:
         «  #  Concat the top two parts on the stack together
        }¹ý # After the loop: join the stack with the first input substring as delimiter
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: @TheThonnu Ah ok. That's just the way I make my comments for filters/maps/if-statement. I place the `}` below where it was opened. [Here another example of that.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253550/52210)

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

Expects `(string, substring, n)`.

```javascript
(s,q,n)=>(a=s.split(q))[n]+1?a.map(s=>a[++n]+1?s+q:s).join``:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrNCoMwEITvfYrFU0I0IPSkjT30MaRg8KeNxF11Qz2UPnuqXuYb5pvRfiy3q5tDhtT1cTBRcLqkKE0lrGHNs3dBLFLW@FT53erJzoJNZWulzoXVUrDUIzlsmoLjQKtAMJCXgHAzcN2plITvBaAlZPK99vQSg0geNjB0BFNPW3YEbG/ne/Bu/x0CKZxSJykkR9mJUpaXX/wD)

#### Commented

```javascript
(s, q, n) => (   // s = string, q = substring, n = integer
  a = s.split(q) // split s on q and save the result in a[]
                 // if q appears x times, we get x + 1 entries
                 // some of these entries may be empty strings (falsy)
                 // so we do '+ 1' to distinguish between empty and undefined
)[n] + 1 ?       // if a[n] is defined:
  a.map(s =>     //   for each entry s in a[]:
    a[++n] + 1 ? //     increment n; if a[n] is still defined:
      s + q      //       append q to s
    :            //     else:
      s          //       leave s unchanged
  ).join``       //   end of map(); join everything back together
:                // else:
  s              //   return s unchanged
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 30 bytes

```
d:a^b#d>c?dZJ(bRL#d-UcALxRLc)a
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJkOmFeYiNkPmM/ZFpKKGJSTCNkLVVjQUx4UkxjKWEiLCIiLCIiLCJcIkNhdHMgZG8gbWVvdy1tZW93IHdoaWxlIGxpb25zIGRvIG5vdCBtZW93LlwiIFwibWVvd1wiIDIiXQ==)

How?

```
d:a^b#d>c?dZJ(bRL#d-UcALxRLc)a
  a                            : First arg(string)
    b                          : Second arg(substring)
        c                      : Third arg(n)
d:                             : Assign d to the result of
  a^b                          : Split a on separator b
         ?                     : If
     #d>c                      : Length of d is greater then c
                    Uc           : Increment c
             bRL                 : Repeat b 
                #d-              : Length of d - c times
                      AL         : Append list
                        x        : Empty String
                         RL      : Repeat x
                           c     : c times
          dZJ                    : Zip with iterable d
                             a : Else return a
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
qW ÔË+WpE>VÃw
qWpUÊ§V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cVcg1MsrV3BFPlbDdwpxV3BVyqdW&input=IkNhdHMgZG8gbWVvdyBub3QgbWVtZW93b3csIHRoZXkgZG8gbWVvdy1pbmciLCA0LCAibWVvdyI)

Input as `string, n, substring`

v2.0a0 is necessary because v1.4.6 errors if you try to use `p` this way.

Explanation:

```
qW ÔË+WpE>VÃw
qW            # Split <string> where <substring> appears
   Ô          # Reverse the array
    Ë      Ã  # For each item in the array:
     +        #  Append:
      Wp      #   <substring> repeated a number of times equal to:
        E>V   #    The current index is greater than <n>
              #    (Boolean gets converted to 1 or 0)
            w # Reverse the new array
              # Store as U

qWpUÊ§V
q             # Turn U into a string by inserting this between each item:
 Wp           #  <substring> repeated a number of times equal to:
   UÊ         #   Length of U (i.e. 1 + number of times <substring> appeared)
     §V       #   Is less than or equal to <n>
              # Output that string
```

I've tried an alternate using `ð` but the best I got was [25 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=VvBVIArKqFc/X2pVbyBOzmx9Z1dbVl06Vg&input=Im1lb3ciLCAiQ2F0cyBkbyBtZW93IG5vdCBtZW1lb3dvdywgdGhleSBkbyBtZW93LWluZyIsIDM).

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 11 bytes

```
O≤[Ẇy?NẎY|_
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiT+KJpFvhuoZ5P07huo5ZfF8iLCIiLCJtZW93XG5DYXRzIGRvIG5vdCBtZW1lb3dvdywgdGhleSBkbyBtZW93LWluZy5cbjIiXQ==)

12 bytes without the flag. Takes `substring, text, n`

### Explained

```
O≤[Ẇy?NẎY|_
O≤          # is the count of the substring in text less than n?
  [      |  # if so:
   Ẇy       #   Split text on substring, keeping the delimiter. Then uninterleave - this gives a list of splits and a list of delimiters
     ?NẎ    #   Take up to the -nth item of the list of delimiters
        Y   #   Reinterleave the delimiters, which will now be shorter than before. The s flag combines all the pieces into a single sting
         |_ # Otherwise, just return the original text
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 169 bytes

```
S=s.length
L=l.length
I=[L-S...1]
A=I[[(l[i...i+S]-s)^2.totalfori=I]=0]
B=\{n>A.\length:[-L],A[1...n]\}
f(l,s,n)=l[[[0^{(b-B)^2}.maxforb=z-[0...S-1]].maxforz=[1...L]]=0]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ebtzvfzgh)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h4iuopiqfa)

\$f(l,s,n)\$ takes in two lists of codepoints, with \$l\$ representing the string and \$s\$ representing the substring, and a positive integer \$n\$, representing the number of substrings to remove. The output is also a list of codepoints.

As you can tell by the byte size of the code, Desmos is not really well suited for problems related with string manipulation (When was using Desmos on a string problem ever a good idea?!?!). Also fun fact, this is my first time using a nested list comprehension in Desmos, which is pretty nice. There's probably a better way of doing that part, but nested list comprehensions look cool :P (to be completely honest, I can't think of any better way to do that lol).

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 89 bytes

```
func[s t n][reverse t either parse r: reverse copy s[n to remove t to end][reverse r][s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU4xDsIwDNz7ilNnYEBMXfkBa5ShahwaqY0rJ1D19SFpVRASCx5sn@/OtpBJNzJKV7ZBsg/fqYAIr5XQkyRQBuRiT4KpLVAa7EzH04KgPCLn2cjPIs49efOxi1ZB62RZqO167Nsr5KivbQwwjJF4PpaEuXcDYXDsV8JzXMlTjbrUGudv5yYoFM8H5D@X9z7n79lWxD@df9y8VFpN4nyExfZ/egE)

Working on a reversed copy of the string, I use `parse` to remove `n` times the reversed substring. If `parse` succeeds, I return the modified string reversed, otherwise - the original string.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>75</strike> 111 bytes

Okay so... lot of change

+12 bytes for a bug found by @Ismael Miguel where loop keep running if no instance of searched string given (`strrpos()===false`)

+26 bytes for using $argv instead or pre defined variable as indicated by @Sʨɠɠan

-2 bytes (Hey! an actual upgrade :D) from @Sʨɠɠan who remind me i can just get ride of `{}` for a single line instruction ^^'

```php
for($s=$argv[1];$argv[3]--&&false!==$c=strrpos($s,$argv[2]);)$s=substr($s,0,$c).substr($s,$c+strlen($argv[2]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBDsIgEEWvgglpSmwbtUskLjyGYYFIpQkyhEF7fIQ20c3Ln3n/Bxvy@RIKJ4gtRUFVfH5uR8m3MMq@b5pJOTQ7IagWmGIMgKXabY2TZJyVIb7vxdX/oaOaDf@b6n1Jzvj2t2A8G22BUOQ5X1VC8gDyMrD0FWSxszPEzeBX4SGtcsiVefwC)

Comment: If you don't mind using older versions, like 5.3-5.6 or some 7.x versions, you can reduce by 2 bytes by removing the double quotes.

Comment: Also, you have a bug. The rules say: "If the substring is not present in the string or the number of times the substring appears is less than `n`, then the output is the original string.". For an `n = 5`, on test case `0`, it displays `"not , they do -ing."`.

Comment: Don't even need to downgrade PHP version, juste disable error reporting do the job here, thx for the tip.

I still need to fix that bug without adding to much bytes so ^^'

Comment: The problem is that, on PHP 8.0+, it throws an exception for all constants that aren't defined. In this case, `$t="substr"` works fine in newer versions, but `$t=substr` gives you a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "substr" in [...]".

Comment: You don't need the `{}`.

Comment: However, by our consensus, we [can't take input/output via a variable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/92689). You can try taking input via ARGV, though. That's often shorter than a function

Comment: BTW, it's actually shorter to reference `substr` twice than storing it in a variable, even without the quotes.

Comment: Just a headsup: The answer is not correct. OP now [clarified](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104003/anoman) that `Cats do meow not memeowow, they do meow-ing` where `n=3` should return `Cats do not meow, they do -ing`.

Comment: It might be easier to split the string into multiple substrings, and then work with that new array. This substring method will always fail in the case that JvdV said.

Comment: Hum, spliting into array sounds like a good idea for lisibility/conviniance, but i got some doupt about interest here @IsmaelMiguel since the goal is more to make code shorter, and array operation function aren't that short too, it sill depend on seperator used i guess, maybe with some `array_unshift()`? I gonna looking for that anyway so thanks for the idea ^^'

Comment: @Ratchet2277 Currently, you have a solution that doesn't work. Using an array with `array_unshift()` and removing elements from it, when a `join()` for the remaining elements will get you there pretty quickly. It might even be shorter than what you currently have, and will always work.

Comment: You can use `!1` instead of `false`, saving you 3 bytes. You can save 3 more bytes by saving `$argv[2]` into a temporary variable. This is the final solution: `for($s=$argv[1];$argv[3]--&&!1!==$c=strrpos($s,$x=$argv[2]);)$s=substr($s,0,$c).substr($s,$c+strlen($x));`. But currently, if you change the 3rd argument to `4`, it doesn't show the original string.

Comment: Also, outputting by putting the value into a regular variable is disallowed. And I fixed the bug for you: `for($T=$s=$argv[1];$argv[3]--&&$R=!1!==$c=strrpos($s,$x=$argv[2]);)$s=substr($s,0,$c).substr($s,$c+strlen($x));echo$R?$s:$T;` <-- 124 bytes. This will print `"Cats do - while lions do not ."` for `3` but `"Cats do meow-meow while lions do not meow."` for `4`, for the existing test case, in your link.

Answer (score 4):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 99 bytes

Creates an anonymous function that returns the expected result.

The argument order is `$full_string`, `$substring` and then `$number`.

```
fn($F$S$N)&iff(run&len(&str_split($F$S))>$N&str_rev(&str_replace(&str_rev($F)&str_rev($S)''$N))$F);
```

### How does it work?

First, splits the full string by the substring, and counts the number of elements.

When splitting the string:

- If the substring isn't present, returns 1 element.
- If it is present, returns 1 extra element.
  Example: `&str_split("abcbdbebf", 'b') -> ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`
  For 4 `'b'`s, returns 5 elements.

If the number of elements is higher than `$number`, that means there's at least `$number` substrings in the full string.

The `&iff()` function is just the same as a ternary operator, in C-like languages.

To remove from the end of the string, I need to reverse the string, since there isn't a way to indicate to remove from the end of the string.
However, it takes an argument that indicates how many times to replace, which means, it will replace up to `$number` occurrences.

The result is returned automatically, since it is a function without a scope, just like an arrow function in JavaScript.

### Ungolfed

Code-y looking:

```
$fn = fn($full_string, $substring, $num) => &iff(
    (call &len(&str_split($full_string, $substring))) > $num,
    &str_rev(
        &str_replace(
            &str_rev($full_string),
            &str_rev($substring),
            '', $num
        )
    ),
    $full_string
);
```

Pseudo-code looking:

```
Set $fn to an anonymous function ($full_string, $substring, $num)
Begin.
    Set $count to the result of calling &len(Call &str_split($full_string, $substring)).
    
    Return the result of calling &iff(
        $count > $num,
        Call &str_rev(
            Call &str_replace(
                Call &str_rev($full_string),
                Call &str_rev($substring),
                '', $num
            )
        ),
        $full_string
    ).
End.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 21 bytes

```
s.iJcwz*]zt-lJ*KE>lJK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1gv0yu5vEortqpEN8dLy9vVLsfL@///3NT8ci7nxJJihZR8hbz8EoXcVJBQfrmOQklGaiVIFMTXzcxL1@MyAgA)

#### Explanation

```
s                        concatenate the elements of
 .i                      interleave
   Jcwz                  the input string split on the substring (assigned to J) and
        ]z               a singleton list of the substring
       *                 duplicated
          t              one less than
           -lJ           the length of J minus
              *KE>lJK    0 if substring has less than n occurrences, n otherwise
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 87 bytes

```
.+$
$*
(?=.*¶(.+)¶)\1
¶
rT`¶``(?(1)$)(?<-1>¶.*)+(?=¶.+¶(1)+$)
+`¶(.*¶(.+)¶1+$)
$2$1
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxCgMhEEX7OYWFheOwwmydxGKLXCBlChciRNgobIS9mQfwYka3SPP4/P/@7nOIa2uGJEgNyl6NrkUZwlrwyVAL7A9Xi3PKKkaJyl4mvtViNFK3e6DuM5JEIDeu/z@PTs6Sge@utWXNX/FK4uPTMQ2I4x02L7aQ4jnElM/RwCDMPw) Takes the string, substring and count on three separate lines. Explanation:

```
.+$
$*
```

Convert the count to unary.

```
(?=.*¶(.+)¶)\1
¶
```

Replace occurrences of the substring in the string with newlines.

```
rT`¶``(?(1)$)(?<-1>¶.*)+(?=¶.+¶(1)+$)
```

Remove the last `n` newlines from the string if there are in fact that many. (Today I discovered that an empty "to" string in transliteration is treated as `_`, i.e. delete matching characters.) The `r` causes the regular expression to be evaluated from right to left, so the lookahead gets processed first (setting `$#1`), then the newline-matching loop in the middle, then the count check at the beginning.

```
+`¶(.*¶(.+)¶1+$)
$2$1
```

Replace (remaining) newlines with the substring.

```
1G`
```

Keep only the (final) string.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⪪ηζηＦ›Ｌηθ⊞η⪫⮌Ｅ⊕θ⊟ηω⪫ηζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1NDoIwEIX3nGKW0wRduGVlXBiMGqInqDDSJmVa2gKJl6@lm5fJfO@nV9L3VpqUWnZLfC7ThzzOoqnOIeiR8e2Mjqhq@IkaVP5/rQe8epIxG@/EY1SoMpuFgG4JavferGZ80Uo@ED6kw5Z7TxNxpCGX19BZl0MiX5vInZ3XHLGkypJoUjpVFxkDDBYmstthF9iUNgRGWy6AbSzwWO2aDqv5Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order count, string, substring. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the count as an integer.

```
≔⪪ηζη
```

Split the string on the substring.

```
Ｆ›Ｌηθ
```

If this results in more than enough pieces, then...

```
⊞η⪫⮌Ｅ⊕θ⊟ηω
```

... join the last `n+1` pieces together.

```
⪫ηζ
```

Join the (remaining) pieces with the substring.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 8.x, 65 bytes

This anonymous function does the replacement, up to `$n`, and checks how many replacements were made.
If there were fewer than `$n` replacements made, returns the original string.

```php
fn($F,$S,$N)=>($r=preg_replace("@$S@",'',$F,$N,$x))&&$N>$x?$F:$r;
```

Due to the use of [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), the substring must be a valid regular expression.
Regular words will always be valid regular expressions, and there's no need to worry about it.

### How does it work?

The function [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) takes the following arguments:

- `$pattern` - Which will be the substring, `$S`
- `$replacement` - Which is an empty string
- `$subject` - The full string, `$F`
- `$limit` - Maximum number of replacements, `$N`
- `&$count` - Variable which will hold the number of replacements made

If `$N` is higher than `$count`, returns the full string, otherwise returns the result of the replacement.

## Example

```php
$fn=fn($F,$S,$N)=>($r=preg_replace("@$S@",'',$F,$N,$x))&&$N>$x?$F:$r;

echo $fn('Cats do not memeowow, they do meow-ing.', 'meow', 2);
// Should display: Cats do not meow, they do -ing.
```

You can try this on https://onlinephp.io/c/d08f3

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 42 bytes

```
{$^a.flip.subst($^b.flip,'',:x($^c)).flip}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiUuUS8tJ7NAr7g0qbhEQyUuCczVUVfXsaoAcpM1NcECtf@tixMrFdIUlJwTS4oVUvIVclPzy3VBhEJ5RmZOqkJOZn4eWCIvvwQsqaekowSilXSMuNA1Q9SAZPPLdRRKMlIr4UZm5qXj00mCtSZc/wE)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## Shell, <del>238</del> <del>236</del> <del>220</del> <del>200</del> <del>199</del> <del>194</del> <del>191</del> 186 bytes

(counting the last newline to make the script file containing those commands a real unix text file. Otherwise 185 bytes.)

Can probably be highly optimized, but I found it funny to attempt.

usage:  cat  Text-cases | this_script , or  this_script < Test-cases

```
sed -e'/^O/N;s,\n,,;s,",,g;s, = ,:,g'|awk -F: '/^St/{I=$2}
/^Su/{S=$2}
/^n/{n=$2
R=s=""
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){R=R sprintf("\\(.*\\)%s",S)
s=s"\\"i}
system("echo "I"|sed -e\"s,"R","s",\"")}'
```

Explanation:

```
the sed : 
  1) put the line following "Output:" at the end of that line
  2) takes out the doublequotes
  3) replace " = " by ":"
Then the awk:
  retrieve (I)nput String,
           (S)ubstring, 
       and (n),
  loops on n to construct:
         the (r)egex "\(.*\)S\(.*\)S\(.*\)S" (if n==3)
     and its (s)ubstitution "\1\2\3"
  and use sed to do this search/replace on the (I)nput string.

I used "\n" instead of ";" when I could (in the awk part) as it 
is 1 caracter all the same, and is more legible.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 74 bytes

```perl
sub{($_,$s,$n)=@_;$n*2>(@a=split/($s)/)?$_:join'',grep!/$s/||++$n*2<@a,@a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJdT8IwFIav3a84LsVtUlgc6AVzsMRLErnxTs0ypRvT0c61Bgnw22e7AUocfjdpz2l73vdp02YkT08LFHkFf75bmCjAiGNELc8PXESPnb7phx7P0kTYJuKWbQ1Q0HtgCTUMHOckO7QRt5fLZlMVn/sh9sNV4WoRy03tWr8IBYcxgylhs5YaYDZJUgJpwmi5QZkoN9s6Bl0lMjrg9WFXWidr67f4HaJyUtVshkFMyHyrTmis/GWrR2wO8SarJDv@P7pC9@MVPpf@HnXyfdRfMJ0dzL8/SKfmQfZLJcdaaEo/nctfKXK5igHJH7zNqezkJSP3wgIPfBS463pAsXT34AhF@6RWVZvJuYhAb7TOOECj1XU4LFUsw7jKN2sOv6E61g7WUCBPFWgABns0oAfG5egKRkMDl96qfXVwXDq42qp4BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

`->s,u,n,*a{x=s.split(u);l=x.size-n;x[0...l].join(u)+x[l..].join}`

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3HXTtinVKdfJ0tBKrK2yL9YoLcjJLNEo1rXNsK_SKM6tSdfOsK6IN9PT0cmL1svIz84By2hXROXp6EG4t1Jy7BaUlxQpu0UrOiUA6JV8hNzW_XBdEKJRnZOakKuRk5ueBJfLyS8CSeko6CkogBpA2iuVC1w9RBpLPL9dRKMlIrYSbmpmXjk8zEYaD3YXfBiQDjGMhnlywAEIDAA)

Code is mine - I thought `split` and `join` would be more efficient, but I will credit [Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11261/jordan) above for the tests and framework.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 46 bytes

```
{x(!#x)^,/(!#y)+/:(-z*(~z>#t))#t:&(#y)(y~)':x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJytUU1PwkAQve+vWKhhZ0ppKXpxEr146smDPTZ0MRZogruGbm0Lpb/dLURNlBgOXmYyH++9eZkl7WsYODXOvcDmBscBwWTnQre7dwyiY2gEtg1Nh4LqA2MBY5F6Kw09LEzBXzR/zXQ16QOv1vkm45tcq+NAaXMc+uypfC7MNlcr6mumaMYeS/OL5ByB/1PuxNrv68rjZp01X3grcInW513f6BPyH3zdnPX1N0lihQlcg951agja5HZ255LAdEpysV2985DFJHNZSCX1wL4H3HZIwwRFmKJIgzaEUedYQBIxBktf7KHu19GT0VUt1UHE2AkYxyg1+wDGfJ8U)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
i=input
a=i()
b=i()
c=int(i())
d=a.rsplit(b,c)
print([a,''.join(d)][len(d)>c])
```

Pretty direct approach using Python 3. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtIQr0TZTQ5MrCUwmA8VKNIAsTa4U20S9ouKCnMwSjSSdZE2ugiKQVHSijrq6XlZ@Zp5GimZsdE4qiLZLjtX8/z8pv0ihBIG5QNgIAA)